# I have changed permission of the main folder and cannot login anymore

Tags: 14.04, permissions, login, root, chown

I have changed the permission of 
The root folder, where /tmp and /usr are to:

```
sudo chown - R root *
```

Now I cannot login, only black screen is showing and everything is a mess. 
Is there anyway to reverse it to normal. 
Should I do a fresh install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have accidentaly changed the owner of every folder to be root , thus you are unable to login anymore.

Most probably you havent set the root password , if you have just skip this section:

**Part 1**

- Start the grub menu during the boot by holding Shift/Esc
- Choose the Option which has `(recovery)` at the end of it.
- There will be another menu , from which you have to choose `Drop to root shell promt`
- Then you will see something like `root@ubuntu:~#`
- Use this command `mount -rw -o remount /` to get rid of the read only thing
- Now do a `passwd` , which will prompt you the enter a new password for the root
- Thats done then reboot

Here you have successfully set up a new root password , if you are having problems then refer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password) question.

**Part 2**
Here you are going to change the permissions for your home directory.

- Boot up to the login screen.
- Press `Ctrl + Alt + F1`
- At login type root and enter the password you have set for it in the last part
- Now its time for changing the file permissions for your home folder.For that you have to do a <strike>`chown -R root:username /home/username`</strike> `chown -R <username>:<username> /home/<username>`. Change the username to your username.

Hope it helps , thank you.

Comment: It didn't work. For me, after a great deal of research, it worked only when I changed the owner to be also me: `chown <my username>:<my username> /home/<my username>`.

Comment: Let me update my answer, I guess I was being dumb while writing the answer, I see no reason why root::username would work, it changes the group and not the owner